# Multiple conditions driven by series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that stores where a person is living and it looks something like this:

| SECT | PAD | ROOM | PERSON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 101 | PERSON1 |
| 1 | A | 102 | PERSON2 |
| 1 | B | 101 | PERSON3 |
| 2 | A | 103 | PERSON4 |
| 2 | C | 102 | PERSON5 |

I also have another dataframe that specifies all the SECT/PAD/ROOM combos that make that housing unit special (note: if no start_room and end_room exists that  means all the rooms in that sect/pad is special):

| SECT | PAD | ROOM | START_ROOM | END_ROOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 101 | 100 | 104 |
| 1 | A | 102 |  |  |
| 1 | C | 101 | 105 | 500 |

Is there a way to identify all the housing units that are "special" using the 'special' dataframe and then adding a new column in the first dataframe flagging them. The 'special' dataframe is way way larger, and if I had to manually do a conditional .loc statement to identify all the special housing units, it would take forever. I'd like to be able to just match them programmatically

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for all the people in the first table that matches one of the criteria from the second table. The result would be a df with PERSON 1 and PERSON 2.

Comment: But for SECT 1 PAD A, you have 2 rows in the second DataFrame. So are only 100 to 104 special or all rooms special?

Answer (score 0):

So I would merge the first dataframe onto the special data frame and then add a column with the special condition

```
df_person = pd.DataFrame({'SECT': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
                         'PAD': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
                         'ROOM': [101, 102, 101, 103, 102],
                         'PERSON': ['PERSON1', 'PERSON2', 'PERSON3', 'PERSON4', 'PERSON5']})
df_special = pd.DataFrame({'SECT':[1, 1, 1],
                          'PAD':['A', 'A', 'C'],
                          'ROOM':[101, 102, 101],
                          'START_ROOM': [100, '', 105],
                          'END_ROOM': [104, '', 500]})

df_merged = df_person.merge(df_special, on=['SECT', 'PAD', 'ROOM'], how='left')
rows_to_update1 = df_merged[(df_merged['START_ROOM']=='')&
                           (df_merged['END_ROOM']=='')].index
rows_to_update2 = df_merged[((df_merged['ROOM'].astype('int32')>=pd.to_numeric(df_merged['START_ROOM'], errors='coerce'))&
                           (df_merged['ROOM'].astype('int32')<=pd.to_numeric(df_merged['END_ROOM'], errors='coerce')))].index
df_merged['IS_SPECIAL'] = False
df_merged.loc[rows_to_update1.union(rows_to_update2), 'IS_SPECIAL'] = True
```

It is a fiddly problem though in that your START_ROOM and END_ROOM are a mix of strings and integers. I would suggest not having the the two columns as empty strings to signify all the rooms being special.

Answer (score 0):

Since the rows which are empty imply all rooms are special, you could just fill them with dummy values (the minimum and maximum from the first df) and then get your required result from a merged DataFrame.

Assuming your DataFrames are `df1` and `df2`, you could do:

```
df2["START_ROOM"] = df2["START_ROOM"].fillna(df1["ROOM"].min())
df2["END_ROOM"] = df2["START_ROOM"].fillna(df1["ROOM"].max())

merged = df1.merge(df2, on=["SECT", "PAD", "ROOM"], how="left")
result = df1[df1["PERSON"].isin(merged.dropna()["PERSON"].tolist())]

>>> result
   SECT PAD  ROOM   PERSON
0     1   A   101  PERSON1
1     1   A   102  PERSON2
```